# Subset of a Specific Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was given an example which asked us to write out the below set:

$\{X : X \subseteq  \{3,2,a\} \ and \ |X| = 4\}$

The answer written in the book is $\emptyset$ which seems off to me since $|\emptyset|=0$ while one of the conditions states that $|X| = 4$. I believe the correct answer here is no such set exists, but I'm unsure if that statement is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\{3, 2, a \}$ contains three elements (provided that $a$ is neither $3$ nor $2$). Hence, no subset thereof can contain more than three elements. In particular, there is no subset having four elements.

Comment: I agree, but my problem is that the answer is the empty set which doesn't make sense to me knowing that $|\emptyset| = 0$ so we've not satisfied one of the conditions of the set above.

Comment: Since there is no $X \subseteq \{2, 3, a \}$ such that $|X| = 4$, we conclude that $$ \{ X: X \subseteq \{ 2, 3, a \} \text{ and } | X | = 4 \} = \varnothing .$$

Comment: that makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

As you have understood, no such $X$ exists. Which is exacty why the collection of such sets (which is what is being asked) is the empty set.